# paso a seguir después de crear una web local en php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

tengo una consulta acerca de que pasos debo seguir luego de completar una web en php con mysql (local),para publicarla en la net y que sea visible desde cualquier lado del mundo.

Soy ignorante en este tema ya que soy estudiante de programación bastante inexperto.

Acabo de terminar un proyecto web con base de datos,pequeña aplicación,para portafolio,mi idea es hacer una api para adroid etc, pero ahora no sé que paso seguir.

¿debo comprar un hosting?
¿Como conecto la base de datos de la web?

la verdad es que mi conocimiento se limita a solo local....

cualquier respuesta es bien recibida,disculpen si este tipo de preguntas no va en esta web...

saludos cordiales.

Comment: Quieres comprar un punto com, te recomiendo https://hover.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Buenas  el siguiente paso seria contratar un servidor de hospedaje (HOSTING)Y comprar un nombre de dominio (DNS  por ejemplo www.mirpoyecto.com)

Asegurate que el servicio que contrates pueda soportar APACHE SERVER y MYSQL (en caso de utilizar base de datos)

Una vez lo tengas deberías  conectarte via FTP o desde el panel de control que ellos mismos  te darán para subir tu aplicación a la "net"

los siguientes links son para contratar el servicio de hosting y dns

[www.1and1.com](http://www.1and1.com)

[www.goddady.com](http://www.goddady.com)

hay muchos mas por su puesto

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, bienvenido sin embargo no todas las preguntas se deben responder checa como [answer] y de paso haz el tour [tour] por favor para aprender mejor como funciona el sitio saludos

Answer (score 0):

si no tienes presupuesto puedes subir tu web a hostings gratuitos como 000webhost y hostinger esos mismos hosting te dan la posibilidad de crear tu base de datos y también un nombre de dominio de manera gratuita, claro tiene desventajas adquirir un hosting gratuito ya que tienes la limitante de espacio para tu web y de tu db, también la publicidad que no te preguntan si la autorizas, pero en fin para empezar y que tomes experiencia en esto de los hosting, estaría bien, luego ya con experiencia tu mismo buscas un hosting que se adapte a tus necesidades, otra manera y que en lo personal me fascina es publicar sitios web en la nube ya sea de azure o de aws el proceso para publicar dependiendo de tu proyecto es diferente. Trata de tomar experiencia con hosting gratuitos luego por tu cuenta investiga acerca de azure o aws.

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, bienvenido sin embargo no todas las preguntas se deben responder checa como [answer] y de paso haz el tour [tour] por favor para aprender mejor como funciona el sitio saludos

Answer (score 0):

¿debo comprar un hosting? 
Existen muchos buenos, dependiendo del país en el que vivas. Puedo recomendarte Godaddy que es muy estable pero un poco costosa, o puedes probar con los muy de moda "amazon aws" en los que pagas solo por el tráfico que uses.

¿Como conecto la base de datos de la web?

Cuando tengas al hosting entras al dashboard (cpanel) y encontrarás seguramente un phpmyadmin ahí creas la bd e importas la que estabas utilizando local.

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, bienvenido sin embargo no todas las preguntas se deben responder checa como [answer] y de paso haz el tour [tour] por favor para aprender mejor como funciona el sitio saludos